# Row Align Widget to TextBasline not working

Tags: flutter, dart

My CloseButton Widget is not willing to go inside the row and be Aligned correctly on the textBaseLine ( the green line just under the text)

minimal code :

```
 Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 20.h,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'request_card_for'.tr(),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5?.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 14.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                    const CloseButtonWidget()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

[screen shot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glPCM.png)

I tried, CrossAxisAlign. in row widget

Centering the CloseButton widget

... and nevermind Fixed it lol....

```
class CloseButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CloseButtonWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
**padding: EdgeInsets.zero,** // <--- Fix... iconButton has default padding of .all(8.0), which caused misaligning of IconButton in Row for me
      onPressed: () {
        AutoRouter.of(context).pop();
      },
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.close,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        size: 18,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: Couldn't find this from a quick google search, so leaving it here, maybe it will help someone else facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This works
(more clear to understand)

```
Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'request_card_for',
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .headline5
                        ?.copyWith(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  // **padding: EdgeInsets.zero,** // <--- Fix... iconButton has default padding of .all(8.0), which caused misaligning of IconButton in Row for me
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```